# I am trying to install the Oracle java sdk and jre manually on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: java, jre, jvm, sdk

I installed the Oracle jdk1.7.0_25 and the Jre1.7.0_25 on Ubuntu 12.10. I used the install method at http://www.noobslab.com/2012/12/install-oracle-java-7-in-ubuntu.html. When I execute "java -version", without the quotes, I get the following:
/usr/bin/java: 1: /usr/bin/java: Syntax error: end of file unexpected(expected ")")
Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This is improper installation. Install through Ubuntu Software Center: Go for Open JDK Java6Runtime and Iced Tea plugin for browsers, better way of installation.

```
aman@ubuntu:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
aman@ubuntu:~$
```